# after jexcel update table i am not getting new values

Tags: javascript, spreadsheet

I am not able to get new jexcel data.
When i click save Test column data not working. I have to get the sum
[
  [
    "Honda",
    "2",
    "2",
    ""
  ]
]
Here is my code

```
    var datagrid = jexcel(document.getElementById('my-spreadsheet'), {
    columns: [
        {title: 'Model', width: 300},
        {title: 'Price', type: 'numeric', width: 80},
        {title: 'Tax', type: 'numeric', width: 100},
        {title: 'Test', type: 'numeric', width: 100}
    ],
    data: [
        ['Honda']
    ],
    updateTable: function (instance, cell, col, row, val, label, cellName) {
        if (col == 1) {
            Price = val;
        }
        if (col == 2) {
            Tax = val;
        }
        if (col == 3) {
            totals = Number(Price) + Number(Tax);
            $(cell).text(totals);
        }
    }
});
function save() {
    var data = datagrid.getJson();
    console.log(data, 'data');
}
```

I know there is a formula like =B1+C1 ...
But I have enter manually for all rows in the grid.

Actually it was working as expected in version jexcel 1.5

Comment: What's not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the innerHTML from the cells without changing the data source object. You can fix that using the following code:

```
   var datagrid = jexcel(document.getElementById('my-spreadsheet'), {
    columns: [
        {title: 'Model', width: 300},
        {title: 'Price', type: 'numeric', width: 80},
        {title: 'Tax', type: 'numeric', width: 100},
        {title: 'Test', type: 'numeric', width: 100}
    ],
    data: [
        ['Honda']
    ],
    updateTable: function (instance, cell, col, row, val, label, cellName) {
        if (col == 1) {
            Price = val;
        }
        if (col == 2) {
            Tax = val;
        }
        if (col == 3) {
            totals = Number(Price) + Number(Tax);
            // Update labels
            $(cell).text(totals);
            // Update data source
            instance.jexcel.options.data[row][col] = totals;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `instance.jexcel.options.data[y][x] = totals;` Where do `x` and `y` come from?

Comment: It was a mistake.

Comment: `instance.jexcel.options.data[row][col] = totals;` does not seem to work in my case. This time, I also tried to apply `$(cell).text(totals);` instead of `cell.text = totals`, but that gave me a huge compilation error, I didn't even bother to check the entire thing. So, I changed it back to `cell.text = totals`. Still, nothing works. No matter what I do, I cannot change the text dynamically via `updateTable`...

Comment: Finally found a working solution: `cell.innerText = "myText"`.